# Similar idiom to 'I don't have the staff of Moses'

Tags: idiom-requests

It means that one can't just make things happen magically, or that one is incapable of doing the thing requested immediately. The wording comes from the magical powers that Moses's staff had.

Any such idioms in English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***[I have no magic wand](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/britannico/magic-wand)*** may work:

> - a quick and easy solution:
>
>   - *She warned that she had no magic wand to solve the problem.*

(dictionary.cambridge.com)

Answer (score 0):

***I can't [move mountains](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/move+mountains)***

> **Move mountains:** to achieve something difficult.

thefreedictionary.com

---

Not really an idiom but alternatively you could say ***I'm not [omnipotent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/omnipotent)***.

> **Omnipotent:** Having unlimited or universal power, authority, or force; all-powerful.

thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the impossibility rather than one's inability:

> It's like trying to knit fog.
>
> It's like trying to plait tinned milk.

And focusing on the the ridiculousness of the expectations:

> Yeah, and pigs might fly.